# Supremum of Sum equals Sum of Suprema

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I was studying the [following](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Supremum_of_Sum_equals_Sum_of_Suprema) property of supremum. And I'm getting quite confused because, I'm not sure that it holds for any sequences. For example I can take $x_n = -1^n$ and $y_n = -1^{n + 1}$, so $\sup{x_n} = \sup {y_n}= 1$ and $\sup{x_n + y_n} = 0$ because $x_n + y_n = 0\ \forall n$.

Comment: But a sequence is not a set, your example doesn't apply to that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the definition of $A+B$ which is $\{x+y : x \in A, y \in B \}$.

This is a set which contains all possible sums of an element from $A$ and an element from $B$ so, for your example, if you consider your sequences as defining sets $X$ and $Y$, then $1+1$ is in $X+Y$.